# Count of numbers followed by pipe symbol in a single data of a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, count, csv

`LEN(Column)-len(Replace(Column,'|','')` will give total count of Pipe available in a single row data of a SQL Server.

But I need to count the number of records that has Pipe Symbol followed immediately to Number,

```
**Eg 1:** MNY-THY-**2|** *YUI_WER-NA|JIU-ERT-**8|***
```

The output of the above record is **2**.

```
**Eg 2:** *MNY-YU-NA|*
```

The output is **0**

```
**Eg 3:** *MNY-9876**5|***
```

The output is **1**

**UPDATE TO MY QUESTION BASED ON ANSWERS SUGGESTED:**

```
**Eg 4:** MNY-YU-1234
```

The output is **0** Since there is no '|' symbol in my example 4, the result should be 0 only.

Any suggestion would be highly supportable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2016+, `STRING_SPLIT()` is an option:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   ('MNY-THY-2| YUI_WER-NA|JIU-ERT-8|'),
   ('MNY-YU-NA|'),
   ('MNY-98765|'),
   ('FGL_NU_0003')
) v (TextData)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberCount
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(d.TextData, '|') s
   WHERE (d.TextData LIKE '%|%') AND (RIGHT(s.[value], 1) LIKE '[0-9]')
) a
```

Result:

```
TextData                         NumberCount
MNY-THY-2| YUI_WER-NA|JIU-ERT-8| 2
MNY-YU-NA|                       0
MNY-98765|                       1
FGL_NU_0003                      0
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes it's above 2016 only. Shall I use direct column name instead of hardcoded values? The three data are sample values and I need to use the query as a single filed that should apply for all the data of the table.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar Yes, use your table and column.

Comment: Great. Let me try it out now itself :)

Comment: Dear @Zhorov, The query is working but it is showing count one for FGL_NU_0003. How does it showing 1 for a data which doesn't have '|' ?

Comment: @SathiyaKumar Because `STRING_SPLIT()` successfully parses the data without `|` separator. Use an additional condition in the `WHERE` clause, if you have strings without the `|` separator.

Comment: Plus 1. Excellent @Zhorov. That worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can Split the String based on the "|" and Check the value from the right Side whether it contains number or not.

```
DECLARE @tosearch VARCHAR(MAX)='%[0-9]|%' ,@string VARCHAR(MAX)='FGL_NU_0003'

SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN RIGHT(VALUE,1) LIKE '[0-9]' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string,'|')
WHERE @string LIKE '%|%'
```

**Expected Output:**

```
MNY-YU-1234 - 0
```

Comment: Thank you. It is showing as count 1 for a record which doesn't have '|'. Could you please fine tune that as well? Eg: FGL_NU_0003

Comment: @SathiyaKumar plz Check now

Comment: Plus 1. Great Man. Thank you for the answer. It worked great.